# In Ember, how can I push to an array in the route from a component

Tags: ember.js

In my route I have an array of email addresses:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    recipients: []
});
```

On this routes page, I have an #each that displays a component that displays a users email and a checkbox. How can I push the checked emails to that array?

OR

If I put the array in the components js file, can I access it from the route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I put the array into the route. Then in the component I passed the action along with the user as a parameter.

```
actions: {
     select(user) {
         this.sendAction('select', user);
     }
}
```

Then in the route I created an action of the same name that receives that param.